# Does shift consequence allow damage to be transferred to beings or only to objects?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, demon-the-descent

Does shift consequence allow damage to be transferred to beings or only to objects?

The wording is a bit... complicated, as such I'm a bit unsure if damage can only be transferred onto objects or also onto other beings:

> The demon shifts the consequence to another eligible target. If the consequence is damage, the demon can change it to an inanimate object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does allow damage to be transferred to beings.

I've alway's read that second sentence as a clarification of the first.

Which says the consequence (i.e. damage or inflicted conditions) can be shifted (only) to another eligible target.
This normally means that they can only be transferred to beings, since inanimate objects are not eligible to suffer conditions.
But objects *are* able to be damaged (though perhaps not everyone notices that).
So the second sentence is to forestall argument as to if damage can be redirect to objects.